# Fully automated SQL Server Restore

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-restore

I'm not very fluent with SQL Server commands.

I need a script to restore a database from a .bak file and move the logical_data and logical_log files to a specific path.

I can do:

```
restore filelistonly from disk='D:\backups\my_backup.bak'
```

This will give me a result set with a column `LogicalName`, next I need to use the logical names from the result set in the restore command:

```
restore database my_db_name from disk='d:\backups\my_backups.bak' with file=1,
move 'logical_data_file' to 'd:\data\mydb.mdf',
move 'logical_log_file' to 'd:\data\mylog.ldf'
```

How do I capture the logical names from the first result set into variables that can be supplied to the "move" command?

I think the solution might be trivial, but I'm pretty new to SQL Server.

Comment: Is it that you do not know the logical name at the time you do the restore?

Comment: You'll probably get more and better answers on ServerFault, where the pro DBA's hang out more than here....

Comment: @Thomas, yea, the logical name can be arbitrary

Answer (score 33):

Here's the fully automated restore T-SQL stored proc. Accepts three(3) parameters.

1. Target Database
2. Source Database
3. Fully Qualified backup file name location 
   (`\\yourserver\yourshare\backupfile.bak` or simply `c:\backup.bak`)

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[restoreDB]
    @p_strDBNameTo SYSNAME,
    @p_strDBNameFrom SYSNAME,
    @p_strFQNRestoreFileName VARCHAR(255)
AS 
    DECLARE 
        @v_strDBFilename VARCHAR(100),
        @v_strDBLogFilename VARCHAR(100),
        @v_strDBDataFile VARCHAR(100),
        @v_strDBLogFile VARCHAR(100),
        @v_strExecSQL NVARCHAR(1000),
        @v_strExecSQL1 NVARCHAR(1000),
        @v_strMoveSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
        @v_strREPLACE NVARCHAR(50),
        @v_strTEMP NVARCHAR(1000),
        @v_strListSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
        @v_strServerVersion NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @v_strREPLACE = ''   
    IF exists (select name from sys.databases where name = @p_strDBNameTo)
        SET @v_strREPLACE = ', REPLACE'

    SET @v_strListSQL = ''
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''##FILE_LIST''))'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'BEGIN'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   DROP TABLE ##FILE_LIST '
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'END '

    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'CREATE TABLE ##FILE_LIST ('
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   LogicalName VARCHAR(64),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   PhysicalName VARCHAR(130),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   [Type] VARCHAR(1),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileGroupName VARCHAR(64),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   Size DECIMAL(20, 0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   MaxSize DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileID bigint,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   CreateLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   DropLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadOnlyLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadWriteLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   BackupSizeInBytes DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   SourceBlockSize INT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   filegroupid INT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   loggroupguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   isreadonly BIT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ispresent BIT'

    SELECT @v_strServerVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('PRODUCTVERSION') AS NVARCHAR)

    IF @v_strServerVersion LIKE '10.%' 
        BEGIN
            SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ', TDEThumbpr DECIMAL'
            --PRINT @v_strServerVersion
        END

    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ')'

    EXEC (@v_strListSQL)


    INSERT INTO ##FILE_LIST EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + '''')

    DECLARE curFileLIst CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 'MOVE N''' + LogicalName + ''' TO N''' + replace(PhysicalName, @p_strDBNameFrom, @p_strDBNameTo) + ''''
          FROM ##FILE_LIST

    SET @v_strMoveSQL = ''

    OPEN curFileList 
    FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @v_strMoveSQL = @v_strMoveSQL + @v_strTEMP + ', '
        FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
    END

    CLOSE curFileList
    DEALLOCATE curFileList

    PRINT 'Killing active connections to the "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database'

    -- Create the sql to kill the active database connections
    SET @v_strExecSQL = ''
    SELECT   @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + 'kill ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), spid) + ' '
    FROM     master.dbo.sysprocesses
    WHERE    DB_NAME(dbid) = @p_strDBNameTo AND DBID <> 0 AND spid <> @@spid

    EXEC (@v_strExecSQL)

    PRINT 'Restoring "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database from "' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + '" with '
    PRINT '  data file "' + @v_strDBDataFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBFilename + '"'
    PRINT '  log file "' + @v_strDBLogFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBLogFilename + '"'

    SET @v_strExecSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @p_strDBNameTo + ']'
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' FROM DISK = ''' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + ''''
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' WITH FILE = 1,'
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + @v_strMoveSQL
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' NOREWIND, '
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' NOUNLOAD '
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + @v_strREPLACE


    --PRINT '---------------------------'
    --PRINT @v_strExecSQL
    --PRINT '---------------------------'


    EXEC sp_executesql @v_strExecSQL
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I was after!

I did notice though that I can't find where the following variables are set @v_strDBFilename, @v_strDBLogFilename, @v_strDBDataFile and @v_strDBLogFile.

I noticed this when I ran the script and there was no output for them.

Comment: I think you need to initialize @v_strREPLACE, it was crashing for me and not running without that.

Comment: For SQL 2008 R2, you need to modify the LIKE '10.0%' to LIKE '10.%' in order for it to create the correct amount of columns.

Comment: Why do we need "SourceDatabase"? I think we just need two parameters (path of bak file and target database)

Comment: This doesnt work anymore "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally."

Comment: You should use `RAISERROR`  `WITH NOWAIT` instead of `PRINT`. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1660/using-the-nowait-option-with-the-sql-server-raiserror-statement/

Also, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use a global tempdb table.

Answer (score 10):

RESTORE FILELISTONLY produces a result set that is documented in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx). You then need to iterate this result set and build an appropriate RESTORE ... MOVE... How you capture and iterate the result set depends on your environment. In a C# application you would use a SqlDataReader. In pure T-SQL you would use [INSERT ... EXEC](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC).

The skeleton of a pure SQL solution would be:

```
declare @filelist table (LogicalName nvarchar(128), PhysicalName nvarchar(260), Type char(1), FilegroupName varchar(10), size int, MaxSize bigint, field int, createlsn bit, droplsn bit, uniqueid uniqueidentifier, readonlylsn bit, readwritelsn bit, backupsizeinbytes bigint, sourceblocksize int, filegroupid int, loggroupguid uniqueidentifier, differentialbaselsn bit, differentialbaseguid uniqueidentifier, isreadonly bit, ispresent bit, tdethumbprint varchar(5));
insert into @filelist exec sp_executesql N'restore filelistonly from disk=''D:\backups\my_backup.bak''';

set @sql = N'RESTORE database my_database from disk ''D:\backups\my_backup.bak'' with ';
select @sql = @sql + N' move ' + LogicalName + N' to ' udf_localFilePath(PhysicalName) + N','
from @filelist;

set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql)-1); -- remove last ','
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

This is not actual working code, but just to get you the idea. You can also use a cursor instead of the non-standard assignment-inside-query construction of @sql

Be aware that the list of columns in the result set of `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` differs between SQL Server versions. Refer to the target version specifications for the correct list.

Comment: Is there any way to get last ordered by datebackup from script in order to restore it?

Comment: @Johnny_D: please post questions as separate SO questions, not comments.

Answer (score 7):

Using

- http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/util_restore_all_in_file.asp
- http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/06/13/Restore-Database-Stored-Procedure.aspx

as references, I came up with this .. and I think it works (not tested for backups with multiple files)

```
DECLARE @FileList TABLE
      (
      LogicalName nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
      PhysicalName nvarchar(260) NOT NULL,
      Type char(1) NOT NULL,
      FileGroupName nvarchar(120) NULL,
      Size numeric(20, 0) NOT NULL,
      MaxSize numeric(20, 0) NOT NULL,
      FileID bigint NULL,
      CreateLSN numeric(25,0) NULL,
      DropLSN numeric(25,0) NULL,
      UniqueID uniqueidentifier NULL,
      ReadOnlyLSN numeric(25,0) NULL ,
      ReadWriteLSN numeric(25,0) NULL,
      BackupSizeInBytes bigint NULL,
      SourceBlockSize int NULL,
      FileGroupID int NULL,
      LogGroupGUID uniqueidentifier NULL,
      DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0)NULL,
      DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier NULL,
      IsReadOnly bit NULL,
      IsPresent bit NULL,
      TDEThumbprint varbinary(32) NULL
 );

 declare @RestoreStatement nvarchar(max), @BackupFile nvarchar(max);

 set @BackupFile = 'D:\mybackup.bak'

 SET @RestoreStatement =  N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY
      FROM DISK=N''' + @BackupFile + ''''

INSERT INTO @FileList
      EXEC(@RestoreStatement);

declare @logical_data nvarchar(max), @logical_log nvarchar(max);

set @logical_data = (select LogicalName from @FileList where Type = 'D' and FileID = 1)
set @logical_log = (select LogicalName from @FileList where Type = 'L' and FileID = 2)
```

Comment: This won't work on SQL Server 2005 though. "TDEThumbprint" is a new field for 2008. INSERT INTO @fileList will blow-up in 2005 instances.

Comment: See my answer below. That would fix 2005 vs 2008 version problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
Automate restore w/o needing to know the logical file names.
Specify destination database name, database backup source filename
and .MDF, .LDF and .NDF directories.
I do nightly automated database restores,
and I've been using this code for about a month.
Works for sql server 2008, might work for 2005.
Created by wtm 5/27/2010
*/

 -- BEGIN - MODIFY THIS CODE - create a blank db
if not exists(select * from master.sys.databases where [name]='sc')
begin
    create database sc
end
go
-- END - MODIFY THIS CODE - create a blank db

declare @strDatabase varchar(130)='sc' -- MODIFY THIS LINE - db name
declare @strBackupFile varchar(500)='c:\docs\db-backups\sc.bak' -- MODIFY THIS LINE - source db backup file
declare @strRestoreMDFFilesTo varchar(500)='c:\docs\sqldata\' -- MODIFY THIS LINE - destination restore directory for main files
declare @strRestoreLDFFilesTo varchar(500)='c:\docs\sqldata\' -- MODIFY THIS LINE - destination restore directory for tlog files
declare @strRestoreNDFFilesTo varchar(500)='c:\docs\sqldata\' -- MODIFY THIS LINE - destination restore directory for non-main files

-- other variables used
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max)
declare @strOriginalPhysicalName varchar(150)
declare @strPhysicalName varchar(150)
declare @strLogicalName varchar(150)
declare @intReturn int

-- begin restoring
begin try
    drop table #tmpFilelist
end try
begin catch
end catch
create table #tmpFilelist (
    LogicalName varchar(64), PhysicalName varchar(130), [Type] varchar(1), FileGroupName varchar(64), Size decimal(20, 0)
    ,MaxSize decimal(25, 0), FileID bigint, CreateLSN decimal(25,0), DropLSN decimal(25,0), UniqueID uniqueidentifier
    ,ReadOnlyLSN decimal(25,0), ReadWriteLSN decimal(25,0), BackSizeInBytes decimal(25,0), SourceBlockSize int
    ,filegroupid int, loggroupguid uniqueidentifier, differentialbaseLSN decimal(25,0), differentialbaseGUID uniqueidentifier
    ,isreadonly bit, ispresent bit, TDEThumbpr decimal
)
if not exists(select * from sc.sys.tables) or exists(select * from sc.sys.tables where [name]='not-an-original-table') -- MODIFY THIS LINE - business logic to see if we need to restore the database at all
begin
    print 'Restoring '+@strDatabase+' db ...'
    use master
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = @strDatabase
    use [master]
    exec('alter database '+@strDatabase+' set single_user with rollback immediate')
    use [master]
    exec('drop database '+@strDatabase)
    insert into #tmpFilelist
        exec('restore filelistonly from disk = '''+@strBackupFile+'''')
    set @strSQL='restore database ['+@strDatabase+'] from disk='''+@strBackupFile+''' with '
    set @strSQL=@strSQL+ 'file=1 '
    set @strSQL=@strSQL+ ',nounload '
    set @strSQL=@strSQL+ ',replace '
    set @strSQL=@strSQL+ ',stats=10 ' -- show restore status every 10%
    while exists(select * from #tmpFilelist)
    begin
        select top 1 @strOriginalPhysicalName=PhysicalName, @strLogicalName=LogicalName from #tmpFilelist
        set @strPhysicalName=@strOriginalPhysicalName
        set @strPhysicalName=reverse(@strPhysicalName)
        set @strPhysicalName=left(@strPhysicalName, charindex('\', @strPhysicalName)-1)
        set @strPhysicalName=reverse(@strPhysicalName)
        set @strPhysicalName=replace(@strPhysicalName, '.', '_'+@strDatabase+'.')
        if @strPhysicalName like '%.mdf'
            set @strPhysicalName=@strRestoreMDFFilesTo+@strPhysicalName
        else if @strPhysicalName like '%.ldf'
            set @strPhysicalName=@strRestoreLDFFilesTo+@strPhysicalName
        else
            set @strPhysicalName=@strRestoreNDFFilesTo+@strPhysicalName
        set @strSQL=@strSQL+ ',move '''+@strLogicalName+''' to '''+@strPhysicalName+''' '
        delete from #tmpFilelist where PhysicalName=@strOriginalPhysicalName
    end
    execute @intReturn=sp_executesql @strSQL
end
```

Comment: Tried this with SQL 2008, Replacing "sc" with the database name or a SQLCMD variable like "$(db)". It worked PERFECTLY. It restored both existing and non-existing databases!. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, but in my environment I have many backup files (faster backups), and did need to restore to custom location. This query gets latest full backup info and restores to the path you specify. Tested on SQL 2005/2008.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @BackupFiles varchar(500), @data_file_path VARCHAR(512), @log_file_path VARCHAR(512), @RestoreFileList varchar(2000), @RestoreStatement varchar(3000), @MoveFiles varchar(2000), @DBName varchar(150)

DECLARE @filelist TABLE (LogicalName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, PhysicalName NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL, [Type] CHAR(1) NOT NULL, FileGroupName NVARCHAR(120) NULL, Size NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL, MaxSize NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL, FileID BIGINT NULL, CreateLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, DropLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, ReadOnlyLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL , ReadWriteLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, BackupSizeInBytes BIGINT NULL, SourceBlockSize INT NULL, FileGroupID INT NULL, LogGroupGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, DfferentialBaseLSN NUMERIC(25,0)NULL, DifferentialBaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, IsReadOnly BIT NULL, IsPresent BIT NULL, TDEThumbprint VARBINARY(32) NULL) 

SET @data_file_path = 'E:\SQLData\' 
SET @log_file_path  = 'E:\SQLLog\' 
SET @DBName = 'Adventureworks'

--Get last full backup:
SELECT @BackupFiles=Coalesce(@BackupFiles + ',', '') + 'DISK = N'''+physical_device_name+''''
FROM msdb..backupset S
JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily M ON M.media_set_id=S.media_set_id
WHERE backup_set_id = ( SELECT max(backup_set_id)
                    FROM msdb..backupset S
                    JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily M ON M.media_set_id=S.media_set_id
                    WHERE S.database_name = @DBName and Type = 'D')

SELECT @RestoreFileList= 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM ' + @BackupFiles + ' WITH  FILE = 1 '

IF (@@microsoftversion / 0x1000000) & 0xff >= 10 --TDE capability
Begin
    INSERT into @filelist (LogicalName,PhysicalName,Type,FileGroupName,Size,MaxSize,FileID,CreateLSN,DropLSN,UniqueID,ReadOnlyLSN,ReadWriteLSN,BackupSizeInBytes,SourceBlockSize,FileGroupID,LogGroupGUID,DfferentialBaseLSN,DifferentialBaseGUID,IsReadOnly,IsPresent,TDEThumbprint)
    EXEC (@RestoreFileList)
End
Else
Begin
    INSERT into @filelist (LogicalName,PhysicalName,Type,FileGroupName,Size,MaxSize,FileID,CreateLSN,DropLSN,UniqueID,ReadOnlyLSN,ReadWriteLSN,BackupSizeInBytes,SourceBlockSize,FileGroupID,LogGroupGUID,DfferentialBaseLSN,DifferentialBaseGUID,IsReadOnly,IsPresent)
    EXEC (@RestoreFileList)
End

--next version, do a count on filename, any >1 put in alternate data/log location.
SELECT  @MoveFiles=Coalesce(@MoveFiles + ',' , '') + 'MOVE N''' + LogicalName + ''' to N''' +
    Case When type = 'D' Then @data_file_path+Right(physicalname, charindex('\',reverse(physicalname),1)-1)
    when type = 'L' Then @log_file_path+Right(physicalname, charindex('\',reverse(physicalname),1)-1)
    Else 'Full Text - code not complete'
    END
    +''''
From @filelist

SELECT @RestoreStatement='RESTORE DATABASE [AuctionMain] FROM ' + @BackupFiles + ' WITH  FILE = 1, ' + @MoveFiles + ', NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 20'

Print @RestoreStatement

Exec(@RestoreStatement)
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the versions include SQL 2000. This will work on all of them:

```
use master

--
-- check SQL Server version
DECLARE @sql_ver int;
CREATE TABLE #tmp_sql_ver
(
    [Index] int,
    [Name]  nvarchar(100),
    [iVal]  int,
    [cVal]  nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #tmp_sql_ver EXEC('xp_msver ProductVersion');
IF (SELECT cast(cVal as char(2)) FROM #tmp_sql_ver) = '8.'
    SET @sql_ver = 8;
ELSE
    SET @sql_ver = 9;
DROP TABLE #tmp_sql_ver;

--
-- get mdf/ldf names
DECLARE @mdf_name varchar(50)
DECLARE @ldf_name varchar(50)
DECLARE @RestoreFileListOnly_columns varchar(2000)

IF (@sql_ver = 8)
BEGIN
    SET @RestoreFileListOnly_columns = '
        LogicalName     nvarchar(128),
        PhysicalName    nvarchar(260),
        [Type]  char(1),
        FileGroupName   nvarchar(128),
        [Size]  numeric(20,0),
        [MaxSize]   numeric(20,0),
    '
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @RestoreFileListOnly_columns = '
        LogicalName     nvarchar(128),
        PhysicalName    nvarchar(260),
        [Type]  char(1),
        FileGroupName   nvarchar(128),
        [Size]  numeric(20,0),
        [MaxSize]   numeric(20,0),

        FileID  bigint,
        CreateLSN   numeric(25,0),
        DropLSN     numeric(25,0) NULL,
        UniqueID    uniqueidentifier,
        ReadOnlyLSN     numeric(25,0) NULL,
        ReadWriteLSN    numeric(25,0) NULL,
        BackupSizeInBytes   bigint,
        SourceBlockSize     int,
        FileGroupID     int,
        LogGroupGUID    uniqueidentifier NULL,
        DifferentialBaseLSN     numeric(25,0) NULL,
        DifferentialBaseGUID    uniqueidentifier,
        IsReadOnly  bit,
        IsPresent   bit
    '
    DECLARE @tmp_ver NVARCHAR(20)
    SELECT @tmp_ver = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('PRODUCTVERSION') AS NVARCHAR)
    IF @tmp_ver LIKE '1[01].%' 
        BEGIN
            SET @RestoreFileListOnly_columns = @RestoreFileListOnly_columns + ', TDEThumbpr DECIMAL'
        END
END
IF EXISTS (SELECT [table_name] FROM information_schema.tables WHERE [table_name] = 'tmp_RestoreFileListOnly')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [tmp_RestoreFileListOnly];
END
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE tmp_RestoreFileListOnly ('+@RestoreFileListOnly_columns+');');

INSERT INTO tmp_RestoreFileListOnly EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @bkpfile + '''')
PRINT 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @bkpfile + ''''
--IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 2 RETURN
SELECT @mdf_name = LogicalName FROM tmp_RestoreFileListOnly WHERE Type = 'D'
SELECT @ldf_name = LogicalName FROM tmp_RestoreFileListOnly WHERE Type = 'L'
DROP TABLE tmp_RestoreFileListOnly
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help. I wanted to create a script for a client with the minimum variables required to be set for multiple database backups restored from a single location. I tried to avoid using dynamic SQL because I think it all gets a little messy.

```
-- Use VARCHAR as the restore statement doesn't like NVARCHAR
DECLARE @data_file_path VARCHAR(512), @log_file_path VARCHAR(512), @backup_path VARCHAR(512),
        @backup_extension VARCHAR(4), @mdf_extension VARCHAR(4), @ldf_extension VARCHAR(4)

-- ** VARIABLES THAT MUST BE SET **--
SET @data_file_path = 'E:\DataPath\'
SET @log_file_path  = 'F:\LogPath'
SET @backup_path =    'B:\BackUpPath'
-- **----------------------------**--

SET @backup_extension = '.bak'
SET @mdf_extension = '.mdf'
SET @ldf_extension = '.ldf'

DECLARE @DATABASES_TO_RESTORE TABLE (rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, backup_name VARCHAR(64), restore_as VARCHAR(64))

-- ** Declare the Databases to be Restored ** --
INSERT INTO @DATABASES_TO_RESTORE
    SELECT 'Intranet', 'Intranet_Test'
    UNION
    SELECT 'TestAudit', 'TestAudit_Test'
-- ** -------------------------------------** --

DECLARE @max_rows INT, @row_count INT
SET @row_count = 1
SELECT @max_rows=count(*) FROM @DATABASES_TO_RESTORE

WHILE @row_count <= @max_rows
BEGIN
    DECLARE @backup_name VARCHAR(32), @restore_as VARCHAR(32), @logical_data_name VARCHAR(64), @logical_log_name VARCHAR(64),
            @data_file_full_path VARCHAR(512), @log_file_full_path VARCHAR(512), @full_backup_path VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @backup_name = backup_name, @restore_as = restore_as FROM @DATABASES_TO_RESTORE WHERE rownum = @row_count    
    SET @full_backup_path = @backup_path + @backup_name + @backup_extension

    DECLARE @filelist TABLE (LogicalName NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, PhysicalName NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL, [Type] CHAR(1) NOT NULL, FileGroupName NVARCHAR(120) NULL, Size NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL, MaxSize NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL, FileID BIGINT NULL, CreateLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, DropLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, ReadOnlyLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL , ReadWriteLSN NUMERIC(25,0) NULL, BackupSizeInBytes BIGINT NULL, SourceBlockSize INT NULL, FileGroupID INT NULL, LogGroupGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, DfferentialBaseLSN NUMERIC(25,0)NULL, DifferentialBaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL, IsReadOnly BIT NULL, IsPresent BIT NULL, TDEThumbprint VARBINARY(32) NULL)

    INSERT into @filelist
        EXEC ('RESTORE FilelistOnly FROM DISK = ''' + @full_backup_path + '''')

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 2
    BEGIN
        SELECT @logical_data_name = LogicalName FROM @filelist WHERE [Type] = 'D'
        SELECT @logical_log_name  = LogicalName FROM @filelist WHERE [Type] = 'L'

        SET @data_file_full_path = @data_file_path + @restore_as + @mdf_extension
        SET @log_file_full_path = @log_file_path + @restore_as + @ldf_extension

        RESTORE DATABASE @restore_as
        FROM DISK = @full_backup_path
        WITH
        FILE = 1, 
        MOVE @logical_data_name 
        TO @data_file_full_path,
        MOVE @logical_log_name 
        TO @log_file_full_path
    END
    ELSE
        PRINT 'CANNOT RESTORE DATABASE ' + @restore_as + ' THE BACKUP CONTAINS MORE THAN 1 BACKUP SET'

    SELECT @row_count = @row_count + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another modification/implementations. 
Here's my 2 cents. I have modified Mevdiven's script above, so that it will restore the file to the current database data directory. I have a problem in that I do not want to use the location defined in the back up file.

I grab the data directory used by the first master file

```
SELECT top(1) @v_strRestorePath =  physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

And use that as my destination data path.

I also found that the ##FILE_LIST table was hanging around, so I drop it near the end.

The extra **--'** are just so the SQL looks nice on Stack overflow

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[restoreDB]') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC [dbo].[restoreDB]
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[restoreDB]
    @p_strDBNameTo SYSNAME,
    @p_strDBNameFrom SYSNAME,
    @p_strFQNRestoreFileName VARCHAR(255)

AS 
DECLARE 
    @v_strDBFilename VARCHAR(100),
    @v_strDBLogFilename VARCHAR(100),
    @v_strDBDataFile VARCHAR(100),
    @v_strDBLogFile VARCHAR(100),
    @v_strExecSQL NVARCHAR(1000),
    @v_strExecSQL1 NVARCHAR(1000),
    @v_strMoveSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
    @v_strREPLACE NVARCHAR(50),
    @v_strTEMP NVARCHAR(1000),
    @v_strListSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
    @v_strServerVersion NVARCHAR(20),
    @v_strRestorePath varchar(500)

SET @v_strREPLACE = ''   
IF exists (select name from sys.databases where name = @p_strDBNameTo)
    SET @v_strREPLACE = ', REPLACE'

SET @v_strListSQL = ''
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''##FILE_LIST''))'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'BEGIN'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   DROP TABLE ##FILE_LIST '
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'END '

SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'CREATE TABLE ##FILE_LIST ('
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   LogicalName VARCHAR(64),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   PhysicalName VARCHAR(130),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   [Type] VARCHAR(1),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileGroupName VARCHAR(64),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   Size DECIMAL(20, 0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   MaxSize DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileID bigint,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   CreateLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   DropLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadOnlyLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadWriteLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   BackupSizeInBytes DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   SourceBlockSize INT,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   filegroupid INT,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   loggroupguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   isreadonly BIT,'
SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ispresent BIT'

SELECT @v_strServerVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('PRODUCTVERSION') AS NVARCHAR)

IF @v_strServerVersion LIKE '10.%' 
    BEGIN
        SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ', TDEThumbpr DECIMAL'
        --PRINT @v_strServerVersion
    END

SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ')'

EXEC (@v_strListSQL)

-- We want to get the current data path from this server as the backup file paths may not be the same on the server
-- especially wehen switching between Express/Standard instances
SELECT top(1) @v_strRestorePath =  physical_name FROM sys.master_files;
set  @v_strRestorePath = REPLACE(@v_strRestorePath, RIGHT(@v_strRestorePath, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@v_strRestorePath))-1),'')
--print @v_strRestorePath --'

INSERT INTO ##FILE_LIST EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + '''')

-- want to see whats in the fillist?
--SELECT * FROM  ##FILE_LIST

DECLARE curFileLIst CURSOR FOR 
    -- Here we restore each file to the current server restore path. Right(...) grabs the file name from the back up
    SELECT 'MOVE N''' + LogicalName + ''' TO N''' + @v_strRestorePath + Replace(RIGHT(PhysicalName, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(PhysicalName))-1),@p_strDBNameFrom, @p_strDBNameTo) + ''''  --'
      FROM ##FILE_LIST

SET @v_strMoveSQL = ''

OPEN curFileList 
FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @v_strMoveSQL = @v_strMoveSQL + @v_strTEMP + ', '
    FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
END

CLOSE curFileList
DEALLOCATE curFileList

PRINT 'Killing active connections to the "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database'

-- Create the sql to kill the active database connections
SET @v_strExecSQL = ''
SELECT   @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + 'kill ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), spid) + ' '
FROM     master.dbo.sysprocesses
WHERE    DB_NAME(dbid) = @p_strDBNameTo AND DBID <> 0 AND spid <> @@spid

EXEC (@v_strExecSQL)

PRINT 'Restoring "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database from "' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + '" with '
PRINT '  data file "' + @v_strDBDataFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBFilename + '"'
PRINT '  log file "' + @v_strDBLogFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBLogFilename + '"'

SET @v_strExecSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @p_strDBNameTo + ']'
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' FROM DISK = ''' + @p_strFQNRestoreFileName + ''''
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' WITH FILE = 1,'
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + @v_strMoveSQL
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' NOREWIND, '
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + ' NOUNLOAD '
SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + @v_strREPLACE


--PRINT '---------------------------'
--PRINT @v_strExecSQL
--PRINT '---------------------------'

--For Some reason the file list hangs when I was debugging remove it.
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##FILE_LIST'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##FILE_LIST
END

EXEC sp_executesql @v_strExecSQLter
```

Hope this helps some one too!

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to add comments under a particular solution but I have just implemented the solution provided by Mevdiven above...

There is a slight problem with the drop table in my environment (Server 08 r2). I have had to modify this to use the object id in order to drop successfully.

I also had problems due to a large number of partitions in the backup file, so I had to change the string to be nvarchar(MAX).

I also added ability to restore the database into another directory (as our dev vs prod environments have different paths)

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[restoreDB]
    @p_strDBNameTo SYSNAME,
    @p_strDBNameFrom SYSNAME,
    @p_strBackupDirectory VARCHAR(255),
    @p_strRestoreDirectory VARCHAR(255),
    @p_strFQNBackupFileName VARCHAR(255)
AS 
    DECLARE 
        @v_strDBFilename VARCHAR(200),
        @v_strDBLogFilename VARCHAR(200),
        @v_strDBDataFile VARCHAR(200),
        @v_strDBLogFile VARCHAR(200),
        @v_strExecSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @v_strMoveSQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @v_strREPLACE NVARCHAR(50),
        @v_strTEMP NVARCHAR(1000),
        @v_strListSQL NVARCHAR(4000),
        @v_strServerVersion NVARCHAR(20)

    SET @v_strREPLACE = ''   
    IF exists (select name from sys.databases where name = @p_strDBNameTo)
        SET @v_strREPLACE = ', REPLACE'

    SET @v_strListSQL = ''
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..##FILE_LIST'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##FILE_LIST '
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + 'CREATE TABLE ##FILE_LIST ('
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   LogicalName VARCHAR(64),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   PhysicalName VARCHAR(130),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   [Type] VARCHAR(1),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileGroupName VARCHAR(64),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   Size DECIMAL(20, 0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   MaxSize DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   FileID bigint,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   CreateLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   DropLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadOnlyLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ReadWriteLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   BackupSizeInBytes DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   SourceBlockSize INT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   filegroupid INT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   loggroupguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseLSN DECIMAL(25,0),'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   differentialbaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   isreadonly BIT,'
    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + '   ispresent BIT'

    SELECT @v_strServerVersion = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY ('PRODUCTVERSION') AS NVARCHAR)

    IF @v_strServerVersion LIKE '10.%' 
        BEGIN
            SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ', TDEThumbpr DECIMAL'
            --PRINT @v_strServerVersion
        END

    SET @v_strListSQL = @v_strListSQL + ')'

    EXEC (@v_strListSQL)

    INSERT INTO ##FILE_LIST EXEC ('RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @p_strFQNBackupFileName + '''')

    DECLARE curFileLIst CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 'MOVE N''' + LogicalName + ''' TO N''' + replace(replace(PhysicalName, @p_strDBNameFrom, @p_strDBNameTo), @p_strBackupDirectory, @p_strRestoreDirectory) + ''''
          FROM ##FILE_LIST

    SET @v_strMoveSQL = cast('' as nvarchar(max))

    OPEN curFileList 
    FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @v_strMoveSQL = @v_strMoveSQL + cast(@v_strTEMP as nvarchar(max)) + cast(', ' as nvarchar(max))
        FETCH NEXT FROM curFileList into @v_strTEMP
    END

    CLOSE curFileList
    DEALLOCATE curFileList


    PRINT 'Killing active connections to the "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database'

    -- Create the sql to kill the active database connections
    SET @v_strExecSQL = ''
    SELECT   @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + 'kill ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), spid) + ' '
    FROM     master.dbo.sysprocesses
    WHERE    DB_NAME(dbid) = @p_strDBNameTo AND DBID <> 0 AND spid <> @@spid

    EXEC (@v_strExecSQL)

    PRINT 'Restoring "' + @p_strDBNameTo + '" database from "' + @p_strFQNBackupFileName + '" with '
    PRINT '  data file "' + @v_strDBDataFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBFilename + '"'
    PRINT '  log file "' + @v_strDBLogFile + '" located at "' + @v_strDBLogFilename + '"'

    SET @v_strExecSQL = cast('RESTORE DATABASE [' as nvarchar(max)) + cast(@p_strDBNameTo as nvarchar(max)) + cast(']' as nvarchar(max))
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + cast(' FROM DISK = ''' as nvarchar(max)) + cast(@p_strFQNBackupFileName as nvarchar(max)) + cast('''' as nvarchar(max))
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + cast(' WITH FILE = 1,' as nvarchar(max))
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + @v_strMoveSQL
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + cast(' NOREWIND, ' as nvarchar(max))
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + cast(' NOUNLOAD ' as nvarchar(max))
    SET @v_strExecSQL = @v_strExecSQL + cast(@v_strREPLACE as nvarchar(max))

    --If want to print string need to do in sections due to limitation of print string length

    PRINT 'Exec string: ' +cast(len(@v_strExecSQL) as nvarchar(max))+ ' ***:'
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,0,3999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,4000,7999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,8000,11999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,12000,15999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,16000,19999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,20000,23999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,24000,27999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,28000,31999)
    PRINT substring(@v_strExecSQL,32000,35999)


    EXEC sp_executesql @v_strExecSQL

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new version based on the answers found here. It should work with the latest versions of SQL Server.

Provided with a back-up location, it restores the DB and moves the MDF and LDF files to a specified location.

```
declare @databaseName nvarchar(max);
declare @backUpDiskLocation nvarchar(max);
declare @physicalMDFLocation nvarchar(max);
declare @physicalLDFLocation nvarchar(max);

set @databaseName = '[<DB_Name>]';
set @backUpDiskLocation = 'C:\SQL-BACKUP\<backUP-Name>.bak';
set @physicalMDFLocation = 'C:\SQL\SQLData\<MDF-Name>.mdf';
set @physicalLDFLocation = 'C:\SQL\SQL-LOG\<LDF-Name_log>.LDF'

if (DB_ID(@databaseName)) is not null
Begin
DECLARE @kill varchar(8000); SET @kill = ''; 
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';' 
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE dbid = DB_ID(@databaseName)
EXEC(@kill);
 DECLARE @Alter nvarchar(max); SET @Alter = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @databaseName +' SET offline  WITH Rollback Immediate'
 EXEC (@Alter)
END

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'restore filelistonly from disk=''' + @backUpDiskLocation +'''';

select @sql
create table #filelist (LogicalName nvarchar(128), PhysicalName nvarchar(260), Type char(1), FilegroupName varchar(10), size bigint, MaxSize bigint, field int, createlsn bit, droplsn bit, uniqueid uniqueidentifier, readonlylsn bit, readwritelsn bit, backupsizeinbytes bigint, sourceblocksize int, filegroupid int, loggroupguid uniqueidentifier, differentialbaselsn bit, differentialbaseguid uniqueidentifier, isreadonly bit, ispresent bit, tdethumbprint varchar(5), SnapshotUrl nvarchar(128));
insert into #filelist exec sp_executesql @sql;
ALTER TABLE #filelist add id int identity(1,1)
update #filelist set PhysicalName = @physicalMDFLocation where [id]= 1
update #filelist set PhysicalName = @physicalLDFLocation where [id]= 2
select * from #filelist

set @sql = N'RESTORE database '+ @databaseName +' from disk = '''+ @backUpDiskLocation +''' with replace, ';
select @sql
select @sql = @sql + N' move ''' + LogicalName + N''' to ''' + PhysicalName + N''',' from #filelist;

set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql)-1); -- remove last ','

select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql;

drop table #filelist
```

Comment: I got this error "Msg 5052, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed."

Comment: Could you please try the solution described in the first part of the following article: https://www.dbaservices.com.au/alter-database-is-not-permitted-while-a-database-is-in-the-restoring-state/?