# Web application to automate database restore

Tags: database, iis, web-applications, restore, database-restore

I am trying to have my web application perform a database restore. How should I go about that?

For context, I want to create a we application for users to perform a database restore from the front end. My environment currently uses Microsoft IIS server and Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Like any investigation, you can get started from what are the methods to restore database (such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)). Then the question is whether this method can be used in a web app.

Comment: What I know is that the database can be restored via script like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510295/fully-automated-sql-server-restore